# AlertMe plugin usage in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, installation

I am new to wordpress.. I installed the AlertMe plugin in wordpress and even activated. But not knowing how to use it. Please someone help!

I tried this but knowing is this correct or not too.

add_shortcode('alert', 'alert_me');

Answer (score 0):

if this plugin regis alert shortcode, you can run a shortcode by

```
do_shortcode([alert type="info"]Alert here![/alert]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. now i have a button , when the user clicks on it, the alert should popup.. how do i make use of this plugin now?

Comment: do i need to write this with in the onclick function??

Comment: Alert me plugin is not popup message. It only show message in alert box.
The plugin you should use is [Simple PopUp](http://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-popup/)